# Can't understand zone.js example

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-zone

Here's the code demonstrating zone.js capabilities from [here](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/):

```
Zone.current.fork({}).run(function () {
    Zone.current.inTheZone = true;

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('in the zone: ' + !!Zone.current.inTheZone);
    }, 0);
});

console.log('in the zone: ' + !!Zone.current.inTheZone);
```

The above will log:

```
'in the zone: false'

'in the zone: true'
```

I don't really understand what is it that zone is doing here and how's it related to intercepting events that [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V9Bbp6Hh2YE) talks about.

It outputs `false` the first time because `Zone.current.inTheZone` is `undefined`, and since we changed `Zone.current.inTheZone = true;` that is the value now that is ouputted second time. What's special is `zone` doing here?

Comment: it may help you understand http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/01/22/understanding-zones.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zone allows you to persist some properties across the asynchronous operations encapsulated within the zone. So basically here it shows that there's no `inTheZone` property attached to the current zone. But when you executed `zone.fork().run()` the callback is executed in the new forked zone and the async task `setTimeout` will be executed in this forked zone as well. And you will get the `inTheZone` property inside this zone but it won't be accessible in other zones. Here is probably a better example:

```
Zone.current.fork({}).run(function () {
    Zone.current.inTheZone = true;

    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('in the zone: ' + !!Zone.current.inTheZone); // true
    }, 2000);
});

setTimeout(function () {
    console.log('in the zone: ' + !!Zone.current.inTheZone); // false
}, 1000);
```

As you can see there are two async tasks here. And the setTimeout from the current zone will be executed earlier than the timeout from the forked zone. The `run()` is synchrounous so `inTheZone` should be set to `true` before the first setTimetout is executed. But it's logged as `false` because the current zone can't access the property from the forked zone.